# Configure apache vhost running multiple servers

Tags: apache-http-server, arch-linux, virtual-host, httpd

I want to run a Python 3.* and PHP 7.* server running right next to each other using the following:

```
php.localhost
py.localhost
```

My `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
AddHandler php7-script php
Include conf/extra/php7_module.conf
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/python/app.py

ServerName localhost

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Full `httpd.conf` file [here](https://pastebin.com/Drtuvyd4).

My `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin yesididuse@google.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/php"
    ServerName php
    ServerAlias php.localhost
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/php-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/php-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin yesididuse@google.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/python"
    ServerName python
    ServerAlias py.localhost
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/py-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/py-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
# Static table lookup for hostnames.
# See hosts(5) for details.
127.0.0.1       php.localhost
127.0.0.1       py.localhost
```

And my hostname is `L702X`.

I'm at a loss here, I've scoured search engines followed guides and nothing seems to make sense here, for one how can a route to 127.0.0.1 go to 2 different addresses?

If I'm missing configuration files, comment and I will add. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can a route to 127.0.0.1 go to 2 different addresses

No, the `hosts` file should be interpreted the other way around: Two different *names* translate to the same 127.0.0.1 address ("if you want to reach py.localhost, contact 127.0.0.1") – like two people sharing a phone number.

This does not affect IP-layer routing at all; it's still the same 127.0.0.1 no matter how it was obtained, and packets to it go the same way.

(The same is very commonly done on the Internet, with hundreds of DNS domains resolving to the same web server's IP address.)

The only interesting part is in how *Apache* distinguishes between HTTP requests belonging to different domains – this has already been repeated on this site, but the short answer is that browsers include the domain name *within* the HTTP request (by adding a `Host:` HTTP header).

Comment: Can't believe it took me this long to mark it, I read and up-voted when I saw it cause with your last paragraph I knew where to look. It took some effort but got it partially working as I wanted to. I then decided to remove apache and go with nginx and I have it operational in a much simpler manner. I simply forgot to mark it, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to @grawity's already excellent answer, you should remember that [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) (or in this case your `hosts` file, which serves the same purpose) only maps a name to an IP address -- but there is no inherent IP limit in these name-to-ip mappings. @grawity's example of a phone number (IP) being able to reach different people (names/programs) is a good example.

If there were a mapping rule where a single IP could only be used once, you couldn't run multiple services (even of different kinds) off the same IP, which would be a severe technical limitation. You would need separate IPs (and likely servers) for HTTP, DNS, email, etc. *and* all subdomains (*www.example.com* is a subdomain of *example.com*, for instance, and would require a separate IP from *example.com*).

Since there is no such limit in these mappings, programs normally contact a server on different ports to separate traffic. Note that ports are not included in DNS entries (or your `hosts` file) -- it is up to individual pieces of software to decide which ports they should use to communicate. If multiple requests for different names are received on a single (port 80 or 443 for regular web traffic) it is then up to the server (which resides at 127.0.0.1 in your case) to decide what it should do e.g. if it receives a request for `php.localhost` or `py.localhost`.

This is where name-based [virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) (technically [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) [SNI] for HTTPS) comes in. Your virtual hosts file contains the instructions for Apache that say "If we get a request for this hostname, do X." If there is no name that matches, the server  typically returns an [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) 404 (Not Found). If there is, the virtual host entry tells the server how to proceed (serve pages from this directory, etc.).

---

*Note that your `ServerName localhost` entry in `httpd.conf` is a default host. This host is sometimes served instead of returning a 404 if no matching hostname is found in your virtual hosts file.*

---

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate and clear explanation, it definitely straightened out some questions that arose while messing about. I had already up voted this question, sorry can only mark one. You know how SE rolls ;)

Comment: Lol indeed I do. I appreciate anything, honestly. ;) Really though, I am just glad to know it helped at least a little. =)

Comment: It definitely helped, none of the 2 answers directly resolve the issue. But I'm more of a programmer (active on so), so while knowing most of the terminology I was frustrated I could not figure it out on my own. I eventually managed to get it partially working (2 weeks ago orso with the help of these 2 answers), about 1 minute later I decided to go with nginx instead and removed apache. Set everything up in about 10 minutes, little to no issues. So I guess I'm done with Apache (that has served me well for over 9 years).